# Cant output the status 422 message in console

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, next.js

[here is the screenshot of the output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tMSTE.png) I am using mongodb. created a signup page and now checking whether a user already exists

```
const existingUser = await db.collection('users').findOne({ email: email });

if (existingUser) {
  res.status(422).json({ message: 'User already exists !' });
  client.close();
  return;
}
```

Error message : auth-form.js:7          POST http://localhost:3000/api/auth/signup 422 (Unprocessable Entity)

I should expect this error but i also want to show the text 'User already exists !' in the console

Comment: try logging the response body for the message

Comment: its not helping

Comment: can you show the part where you're trying to log?

Comment: VS code - developers tool - console

Comment: I think @UsamaMasood meant in the code. Show us the code where you're trying to use `console.log` to log the message.

Comment: res.status(422).json({ message: 'User already exists !' });